Grafana Dashboard Provisioning Error: "Dashboard title cannot be empty" Despite Correct JSON Format and File Mounting
Issue Summary
I am experiencing an issue with deploying a Grafana dashboard using Helm in a Kubernetes environment. Despite correctly formatting and mounting the JSON file for a dashboard, Grafana fails to load the dashboard, reporting that the "Dashboard title cannot be empty".
Environment

Kubernetes Cluster: K3S Raspberry Pi cluster
Grafana Deployment: Using Helm
Namespace: monitoring

Problem Details
The problem appears to be that Grafana fails to recognize the dashboard JSON file, even though it is correctly formatted and placed in the correct directory.
Configurations
grafana/templates/grafana-dashboards.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: grafana-dashboards
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    grafana_dashboard: "1"
data:
  pi-cluster-health.json: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "dashboards/pi-cluster-health.json" | indent 4 }}

grafana/dashboards/grafana-dashboards.yaml
{
    "dashboard": {
        "id": null,
        "title": "Raspberry Pi Cluster Health",
        "panels": [
            {
                "type": "graph",
                "title": "CPU Usage",
                "targets": [
                    {
                        "expr": "100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode='idle'}[5m])) * 100)",
                        "legendFormat": "{{`{{ instance }}`}}",
                        "refId": "A"
                    }
                ],
                "yaxes": [
                    {
                        "format": "percent",
                        "label": "CPU Usage",
                        "min": 0,
                        "max": 100
                    }
                ],
                "xaxis": {
                    "show": true
                },
                "gridPos": {
                    "h": 9,
                    "w": 12,
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "schemaVersion": 16,
        "version": 0,
        "refresh": "5s"
    }
}

Verification Steps
ConfigMap Verification
Verified that the ConfigMap is correctly created and contains the JSON:
kubectl get configmap grafana-dashboards -n monitoring -o yaml

Output:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  pi-cluster-health.json: |-
    {
      "dashboard": {
        "id": null,
        "title": "Raspberry Pi Cluster Health",
        ...
    }

File Verification in Pod
Verified that the JSON file is correctly mounted in the Grafana pod:
kubectl exec -it <grafana-pod> -n monitoring -- /bin/sh
cat /var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pi-cluster-health.json

Output:
{
  "dashboard": {
    "id": null,
    "title": "Raspberry Pi Cluster Health",
    ...
}

Grafana Logs
Checked Grafana logs for errors:
kubectl logs -l app=grafana -n monitoring

Output:
logger=provisioning.dashboard type=file name=default t=2024-07-11T02:33:51.503463709Z level=error msg="failed to load dashboard from " file=/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/pi-cluster-health.json error="Dashboard title cannot be empty"

Observations
Despite the JSON file being correctly formatted and placed, Grafana logs indicate that the "Dashboard title cannot be empty". The title is clearly defined in the JSON file.

Described here sounds like a bug. Consider opening an issue in the Grafana's repo. Also, please clarify relation with this question

Hi @markalex, I opened an issue with Grafana in their repository here. As for relation to the question you referenced, I believe the other poster had simply omitted the dashboard's title, whereas I had not.
